# Finding the null column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2005

I want to find a null column value, if it is null then i have to show as empty otherwise i have to show a column values

```
Table1

Column1

Abcd
null
efgh
lkmn
null
...
...
```

Tried Query

```
Select column1, case when column1 = null then 'empty' else column1 end as status from table1

Select column1, case when column1 = '' then 'empty' else column1 end as status from table1
```

The above query is not working.

Expected Output

Column1 status

```
Abcd Abcd
null empty
efgh efgh
lkmn lkmn
null empty
... ...
... ...
```

How to make a query for the above condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `IS NULL` instead of `= null`:

`Select column1, case when column1 IS null then 'empty' else column1 end as status from table1`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `isNull(columnName, '')`
Give it a try

```
Select 
  column1, 
  isnull(column1, 'empty') as status 
from table1
```